# When a node has multiple locations (using location cck), is it possible to filter location results in views based on only one field?

Tags: 7, views, location

I have a content type with multiple location types attached:

- loc_past (Places I've been)
- loc_now (Where I am now)
- loc_future (Places I'm going)

When I create a view that shows nodes of the content type, the node is shown once for each location in each field.  However, I would like to limit the results to one field (for example, show results only for where users are now).

Is there a way to configure Views/Location to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, I have discovered that no, this is not possible.  It's just not the way location is currently implemented; if a node has multiple location fields, they are all "seen" as a single field.